# Does changing metadata reset your ratings? (iOS)

Tags: ios, app-store

When you release a new version of an app on the Apple app store, your ratings for that version of the app start out at no ratings. If I resubmit the exact same binary for review and just change metadata like the screenshots or keywords, will that also happen, or will I get to keep the ratings I've built up for that version of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit the exact same binary.
You need to change at-least the version number. So it'll count as next version.